# Django database modeling

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a scenerio for which im trying to create the database models but I'm not able to find a perfect way to do it Scenerio is as follows .

- let's say there is a company which gives offer on his(companies own site) site and a different offer on other site(like Amazon)
- I want to store company details for which I did something as below.
- Next I have created the Direct Offers
- Last I have created Vendors offer
- All the models are as below

```py
    class Company(models.Model):
        name= models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
        address= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    
    class DirectOffers(models.Model):
        Smartphone= models.FloatField(max_length=50, null=True)
     
    class VendorsOffers(models.Model):
        Smartphone= models.FloatField(max_length=50, null=True)
        category = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
        owner=models.ForeigKeyField("Company",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But the above doesn't seems right So any help or guidance will be a great help.

Comment: you can have a ```Offers``` table only, and then can have boolean fields like ```for_vendors``` and ```for_direct```?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    address= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

class Offer(models.Model):
    owner=models.ForeigKeyField("Company",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Smartphone= models.FloatField(max_length=50, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vendor_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # company flag denotes that the offer is only applicable on the company site.
    company_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # this will create another table `vendor_offers` to store the details of the vendors for which a certain offer is applicable  
    vendors = models.ManytoManyField("Vendors")
```

This also makes Querying easy

```
#getting offers only for a specific vendor    
Offer.objects.filter(vendors__vendor=21)
#getting offers only for vendors    
Offer.objects.filter(vendor_only=True)
#getting offers which are available both places     
Offer.objects.filter(vendor_only=True,company_only=True)
```

Comment: A unique Offer model is the way to go. Implementation details can vary depending on your needs but the global approach Noah provided is good.